# System.nanoTime / System.currentTimeMillis = 107 (should this be 1e6 ?)

Tags: java, scala

According to [java.lang.System API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)

> currentTimeMillis() Returns the current time in milliseconds
>
> nanoTime() Returns the current value of the running Java Virtual
>   Machine's high resolution time source, in nanoseconds.

Strictly speaking a nanosecond is 1e-9 and millisecond is 1e-3. Therefore, a duration in nanosecs must be a multiple of 1e6 of the same duration in millisecs. This is not the case in practice, what is the reason?

```
scala> System.nanoTime / System.currentTimeMillis
res0: Long = 107
```

Comment: Read on in the javadocs and you'll see under nanotime: This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`System.nanoTime()` has an arbitrary start point; it's not unix epoch. [From the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--):

> The value returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary origin time

So what you're actually calculating there is:

```
(unknownOffset + offsetFromEpochInNanos) / offsetFromEpochInMillis
```

which will almost certainly not be 1e6, unless `unknownOffset` happens to be arbitrarily zero.

If you can remove the effect of the unknown offset by subtracting the two times, you can see that the ratio is around 1e6:

```
long nanoStart = System.nanoTime();
long milliStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

Thread.sleep(2000);

long nanoEnd = System.nanoTime();
long milliEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();;

long nanoDelta = nanoEnd - nanoStart;
long milliDelta = milliEnd - milliStart;

System.out.println((double) nanoDelta / milliDelta);
```

Output (running 5 times):

```
1000058.3725
1000045.4705
999549.1579210395
1000046.101
1000038.1045
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/9xBJsh)

So, pretty close to 1e6.

Note that it *might* not be this, because `System.currentTimeMillis()` doesn't progress smoothly, owing to corrections for clock skew. However, these should be infrequent, so *most of the time* when you run this code, you'll see roughly 1e6.

Comment: Thank you very much for the very clear explanation and demonstration. Ouch for the downvotes in my OP. What a shame, look like everybody already knew this nanoTime vs currentTimeMillis business in Java.